# How to put hyperlinks on video

Tags: javascript, video, hyperlink, html5-video

I need to add clickable link to a video (like the annotation on youtube that are not available anymore).

So, I need to insert some text and when I click on it I need to be sent to another page.

This text has to be visible only in specific part of the video.

How can I do that?

Comment: We need more context. How are you displaying the video, what is the video inside and what styles are applied to the video frame?

Comment: Are you using video tags or something different? You need an actionable button?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a wrapper for the video as overlay in order to place an element. Check this:

```js
$('.skipper').on('click', () => {
  console.log('Button clicked');
})
```

```css
.videowrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.skipper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
  border:0;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videowrapper">
<video style="width: 400px;"><source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4"></video>
<button class="skipper">SKIP AD</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but in this way I see the button for the whole duration of the video, but I need to show it just at specific moments.

Comment: Specific moments? Plural? Well then you will need to implement a logic. Use video event listeners and make the button visible after x seconds, during x seconds... and so on.

Comment: Yes, is there a guide or something I can follow to create the event listeners?

Comment: Google is your best friend :D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events